# Angular - using router with wild card does not reinitialize component

Tags: angular

I have a scenario where the user is presented with a list of files/folders based upon their url. If the user clicks on one of these folders, they are taken one level deeper and shown the contents of that folder.

The problem is that navigating to the "deeper" URL does not prompt the component to reinitialize and fetch the data for that new location. I believe that the reason is because I define the route with a wild card and changing the URL within that wild card does not change anything from Angular's perspective.

If I enter the deeper URL myself and reload the app, it presents the correct data.

Path definition:

```
{
    path: 'Workspace',
    children: [
        { path: '**', component: WorkspaceComponent },
    ]
}
```

How I navigate to a new folder's location when clicked.

```
goToUrl( file )
{
    let url = this.Router.url;
    this.Router.navigateByUrl( url+'/'+file.name );
}
```